# Facebook Graph API. Invalid Scopes: pages_manage_posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I recently received task to extend existing web application functionality. I need to get users permission "pages_manage_posts" and use it to publish some posts(builded by users) at their feed by cron.
I've created test application(I am Admin) and trying to login using JS SDK function:

```
FB.login(function(loginResponse)
{
    // ...
}, {
    scope: 'pages_manage_posts'
});
```

But getting following error:

```
Invalid Scopes: pages_manage_posts. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
```

`Graph API v8.0`

Am I missing something? I thought I can get any permission for test application without problems. Should I request this permission some other way?

Any help with that please.

Answer (score 3):

Check your App Type. For exameple, if yours is Consumer type you can't request pages_* permissions. If you have a typed app, no need to re-create it. You may remove your App Type by going to App Dashboard > App Review > Permission and Features > Looking for additional permissions and features? and clicking the Remove App Type button. You can also check if the list includes the permission you want. If not, you can't request that with "scopes".

When you first create the app you are presented with a few choices, and for testing you could just choose the "Something Else".